# Что такое компоновщик, как он связан с компиляторм и как он работает?

Tags: компилятор, компоновщик

Что такое компоновщик, как он связан с компиляторм и как он работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         --> ╔═════════════╗ -->           ---> ╔═══════════════╗ -->
Исходный --> ║  Компилятор ║ --> Объектный ---> ║  Компоновщик  ║ --> Исполняемая
  код    --> ╚═════════════╝ -->    код    ---> ╚═══════════════╝ -->  программа
```

Компилятор преобразует исходный код в машинный или объектный код, понятный компьютеру.
Компоновщик собирает объектные файлы проекта и используемых библиотек и формирует из них программу, готовую к исполнению.

Comment: Неужели Вы считаете, что стало понятней? ;)

Comment: Ну а что вы хотите о них знать? Они используются вместе, последовательно (сначала компилятор, потом компоновщик). Компилятор преобразует ваш код в компьютерный код, компоновщик ищет все подключенные функции библиотек (например вы можете использовать `printf()` из `stdio` - код этой функции отсутствует в объектном коде вашей программы) и объединяет все объектные коды в один EXE-файл или DLL-файл.

Comment: Продвинутые пользователи могут знать, какие-то оптимизации можно провести в исходном коде программы, какие-то оптимизации на этапе компилирования, какие-то на этапе компоновки - последние две заключаются в использовании правильного набора ключей в командах запуска этих компилятора и компоновщика.

Comment: В целом, большего не обязательно знать для их успешного использования.

Comment: Если провести аналогию с архиватором. Чтобы успешно пользоваться архиватором, вам необходимо понимать три факта: 1) архиватор при архивировании из нескольких файлов получает один файл архива, 2) архиватор при распаковке из файла архива получает несколько файлов, которые были упакованы в этот архив, 3) размер файла архива часто меньше суммы размеров файлов, запакованных в этом архиве. При этом для использования архиватора, вам не обязательно знать что там под капотом этого WinRAR.  Правильно ведь?